# Access an exported module in my d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I have a d.ts file in react-native

**@types/react-native/index.d.ts**

```
export interface ViewProps
```

I want to access that type within my d.ts file.

**globals.d.ts**

```
declare let View: React.ComponentType<ViewProps>;
```

The only way I've managed to make this work is to add the following to react-native/index.d.ts which I don't want to do.

**Adjusted @types/react-native/index.d.ts**

```
export as namespace ReactNative;
```

Is there a way to access the ViewProps interface without adjusting the type file in node_modules?

**My solution**

I think the answer from @barinbritva is correct, however for some reason my IDE (Webstorm) does not seem to like me importing any modules in the d.ts file, as soon as I add any import it seems to break any type detection I had.

**patch the type file to export the namespace**

**@types+react-native+0.63.1.patch**

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts b/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts
index d272ac7..2c4e92b 100644
--- a/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts
+++ b/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts
@@ -64,6 +64,8 @@
 /// <reference path="LaunchScreen.d.ts" />
 
 import * as React from 'react';
+// tslint:disable-next-line:export-just-namespace
+export as namespace ReactNative;
 
 type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

**global.d.ts**

```
declare let View: React.ComponentType<ReactNative.ViewProps>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of TypeScript do you use? If 3.8 and above try in your `globals.d.ts` import types from `@types/react-native/index.d.ts` using this:

```
import type { ViewProps } from 'react-native'
```

If TypeScript version is below then 3.8 you can do next:

```
import { ViewProps } from 'react-native'
```

Comment: 3.9.7, it's so odd but as soon as I add any import within global.d.ts it invalidates the type. I'm not sure whether this is more a fault of webstorm. I've got it working via, export namespace and then using ReactNative.ViewProps and that totally works, I may just go with that and use patch-package.

Comment: Really strange. The error appears only on Webstorm side? Or build through `tsc` didn't work neither?

Did you put `global.d.ts` inside of `src` folder? If not, did you add `global.d.ts` in `includes` section of `tsconfig.json`?